# moment unix cheking valid date

Tags: javascript, momentjs

how do I check if the date has passed unix time?

check if the date has passed

```
var now = moment().unix()
var old = moment().add(1, 'd').unix() // example: 1677219046

console.log(now > old) // don`t work
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work? `1d` after now makes `now > old` false right? Whwat is your question?

Comment: BTW: Moment has a `isBefore` and `isAfter` methods, you should use those

Comment: You are adding one day to "old" instead of subtracting. 1 day after "now" is larger than "now"